# Bluetooth connection doesn't work with my Nokia 2760 due to a dbus error

Tags: bluetooth

My Ubuntu does not work with Bluetooth and a [Nokia 2760](http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/nokia-2760). The error message is:

> Could not display "`obex://[00:1D:6E:3A:3C:2C]/`".
>   Error: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
>   Please select another viewer and try again.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your phone is detected but rejecting the connection.  Try settting up the device through the phone and then the computer.  You may need to enter an alpha numeric code to complete the connection.